# Getting Pixel-data from the canvas with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to get pixel-data from the canvas. There is already an existing and working animation which was built using the KineticJS-library. All I want to do now is to get the rgb-values of some pixels in a specific square.

By using:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'));
```

I already figured out that there are 2 canvas produced by KineticJS. I tried to get the job done with the following code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]; 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");         
var imageData = context.getImageData(20, 20, 10, 10);
```

However, this caused an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of undefined (I tried it both with [0] and [1]). The reasoning here beeing, that document.getElementsByTagName('canvas') should give me a Node-List, from which I thought I would be able to get a canvas object.

With the console.log() mentioned above I already saw that there are two canvas objects, but I am not able to get the context of either one of them.

Has anyone a Tip on how I could get those 3 lines of code working?

Answer (score 0):

May be you doing this before kinetic initing? Looks like your `canvas` has length equals 0.

This example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/ft8M7/3/

Comment: Alternatively, you could use this method of getting the real context for a specific layer (Useful if there are more than 1 layers on the stage):  var realContext = layer.getContext()._context;

Comment: Hello lavrton & MarkE.
It's working! The Problem was indeed that I inserted the code when the layers still weren't added to the stage. The layers are added to the stage in a imageObj.onload-function (where I load the Background pic)... Thanks for your help!